# GetStackTrace in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, exception, stack-trace, delphi-7

Using Delphi 7, how can I get a string representing the stack-trace from an `Exception`?

```
try
  SomethingDodgy();
except
  on E:Exception do begin
    // print stack trace
    Log.Write(/* ??? */);
  end;
end;
```

I hear there's a GetStackTrace function in the latest delphi, but I can't find anything for delphi 7. No, upgrading is not an option :)

Comment: Note that the `GetStackTrace` method in newer Delphi versions does not actually return a stack trace. You do need an external exception framework anyway.

Comment: You can have JCL set up in minutes. I posted an example on this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259563/good-os-delphi-exception-handling-libraries/1260262#1260262

Answer (score 15):

You could try using [madExcept](http://www.madshi.net/madExceptDescription.htm), a wonderful Exception handling framework.

madshi has heaps of sample code in there; I'm sure I've used the stack-trace stuff in there before.

As Dmitriy noted, the [JCL](http://jcl.delphi-jedi.org/) also has stack-trace code; an old sample is [here](http://dcleggsblog.blogspot.com/2005/05/another-example-why-i-love-jcl.html).

Comment: Yeah, madExcept is awesome - but this is commercial code I'm writing, and I don't think I can get the company to buy madExcept right now. JCL sounds good too though, I will take a look..

Comment: It's not all that expensive.  How many hours of work should you spend working around this??

Comment: Yeah - but the stack trace is a nice-to-have in this project, so I won't spend much time trying to work around it.

Comment: Detailed JCL tutorial: http://robstechcorner.blogspot.com/2009/04/finding-hard-to-reproduce-errors.html

Answer (score 5):

I throw [EurekaLog](http://www.eurekalog.com/index_delphi.php) in the game. It's a great tool and not expensive at all.

Answer (score 1):

[MemChk](http://v.mahon.free.fr/pro/freeware/memcheck/) is pretty easy to use (especially to search/find memory leaks) and knows how to render a stack trace from a code address.

Answer (score -1):

The stack-trace in Win32 is not as good as .NET's or Java's (and the latest versoin of Delphi uses .NET stack trace).
Anyway, I found one link that provides more information on it [here](http://www.google.com/search?q=Q_20522255+Jedi+Code+Library+-+Runtime+Call+Stack+%3A+delphi%2C+stack%2C+call++) (It is at ExeEx so to allow to view that solution click the first link on the search).

See the bottom of the page there.

Comment: -1. Experts Exchange: "All comments and solutions are available to Premium Service Members only."

Comment: I told you read at the BOTTOM!
There are solutions.

Please read properly before downvoting!

Comment: @Dmitriy: No there are no solutions. Not at the bottom and not anywhere else.

Comment: ExEx is sneaky. If you google for the URL, and then click the link from google, your referer will be google, and they will show you the solutions.

Comment: The sooner SO kills them, the better.

Comment: @Blorgbeard, thanks for pointing that out. SO is already killing it :)

Comment: @Dmitriy - EE will only display the answers at the bottom in certain web browsers (ie, *not* IE ;)

Comment: @moobaa, ohh my ... That is so ridiculous!

Comment: I just tried it with Firefox and IE7 - I get different pages but both show the answers at the bottom. Re "killing EE": +1 :-)